# How to simplify an expression using Dirac algebra?

Tags: field-theory, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

$$\require{cancel}$$
When encountering Dirac matrices, we immediately resort to using various elementary identities and simplify the expression for example:
$$(a)\  u(p)(\cancel{p}\gamma^\mu \cancel{p})\overline{u}(p')=u(p)((2p^\mu -\gamma^\mu \cancel{p})\cancel{p})\overline{u}(p')=u(p)(2p^\mu m -\gamma^\mu m^2)\overline{u}(p')$$
Where the Dirac equation was used at the end.
But having met an expression like:

$$(b)\ u(p)(\cancel{q}\gamma^\mu \cancel{p})\overline{u}(p')$$
where
$$q=p'-p$$
I thought that it would not be difficult to simplify it in the same way as the example above, but I fell into a stupor, now I'm not sure at all that it can be simplified as easily as the first one. The problem is that the use of identities the same as the first one only leads to a complication of the expression. From what prerequisites do I understand that it can be simplified? Because this expression is relatively simple, let's say what to do with such:
$$(c)\ u(p)(\cancel{a}\gamma^\mu \cancel{b} \gamma^\beta \cancel{c}\gamma^\tau .....\cancel{n}\gamma^\omega )\overline{u}(p')$$

Summing up:

1. Can expression (b) be reduced to a simpler form?
2. Is it always possible to simplify an arbitrarily complex expression composed of Dirac matrices of type (c)?

Comment: *I fell into a stupor.* Did you try moving the $\not p’$ to be next to the $\bar u(p’)$?

Comment: How is (c) going to simplify if there isn’t a $\not p$ or $\not p’$ between the spinors?